# Converting date From one format to another

Tags: php

iam having the date  format stored in database as "20100723"(YYYYMMDD)  and how do i convert it into "23-JUL-2010"

Comment: Not PHP5 specific, please tag correctly. (@Daniel, date() and strtotime() didn't change the OP's end result) http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$original = "20100723";
$converted = date("d-M-Y", strtotime($original));
```

See manual: [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 1):

if php >= 5.3.0

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YYYYMMDD', $dbStoredTime);
echo $date->format('d-M-Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strtoupper(date_create("20100723")->format("d-M-Y"))
```

See the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) class, in particular the [`DateTime::format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method. `date_create` is an alias to the constructor of `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) function, it recognizes the date format in the string and converts it into a Unix timestamp.

```
$time = strtotime("20100723"); // 1279836000
```

Then just use [date()](http://php.net/date) to convert it back into another string format

```
echo date("d-M-Y", $time); // 23-Jul-2010
```

Note that you would have to use [strtoupper()](http://php.net/strtoupper) to make "Jul" upper-case