# Converting date into another format in php

Tags: php, function, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting date From one format to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513719/converting-date-from-one-format-to-another)

I have a date, for example 14th Dec 2011 which I need to convert into
14-december-2011

Is there any php function which could do this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: When you entered that question title into StackOverflow you got a number of suggestions to look at and ***ALL*** of them contain the answer. What made you ask your question then? Please do not ignore http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice. It's shown to you for a reason.

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Converting+date+into+another+format+in+php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`date()`](http://php.net/date) function:

```
date("j-F-Y", strtotime($yourInputDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date('YOUR FORMATTER STRING', strtotime($YourTimeVariable));
```